# Ruby printf output explained

Tags: ruby

Can someone explain and break this down for me please and help me understand why it prints to 1032? I'm especially interested in understanding the % and the `d` and `\n`. Links to the topic that addresses this would help as well.

```
a = 10
b = 3.*(a).+(2)
printf("%d%d\n", a, b) ;
#output = 1032
```

Comment: In addition to the excellent explanation given by Sergio Tulentsev, two suggestions since you are new in Ruby: 1. Bookmark the [Ruby Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/) page for your Ruby version. For instance, if you enter in this page `printf` in the *Methods* fields, you would have found out already much of what you have asked for. 2. Use *irb*, which comes with your Ruby installation, to play with expressions and see their result.... Finally, I would like to point out that there are no *equations* in the code you posted.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could explain which *precise* parts of the documentation are unclear to you, so that the Ruby developers can improve their documentation. That way, future Rubyists won't stumble over the same problem again.

Comment: Also, it would help if you could clarify your question. What "modulos" are you talking about? There is only multiplication and addition in your question, not a single modulo in sight.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect  verbiage as I don't research terms, I just code. Thank you for the excellent answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why it equates to 1032

It does **not**. What it does, it **prints** number 10 and then, immediately after, number 32 (result of 3 * 10 + 2).

It is paramount to learn to distinguish the two: actual value of an expression and its side-effect (text printed to console, in this example).

> I'm especially interested in understanding the modulos and the d and \n

Those are not modulos. `%d` is a format specifier. Means "print an integer here". Read up on [`sprintf`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sprintf).

Comment: It appears that Ruby is disregarding the two periods in `3.*(a).+(2) #=> 32`.  As well, `3.*a.+2 #=> 36`, but `(3.).is_a?(Integer) #=> SyntaxError: (irb):8: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '('` (under the right parenthesis following `3.`). Can you explain this behaviour?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: are _you_ genuinely asking? :) I have a feeling that this kind of detail is two steps above OPs level (not to mention one never sees such expressions in real-life codebases)

Comment: @CarySwoveland what do you mean by _"disregarding the two periods"_?

Comment: I just meant it seems Ruby is evaluating that as `3*(a)+(2)`. I'm just curious. It's getting late here in Victoria, Canada, so I'll check back tomorrow to see if you have any thoughts on this. btw, I am also curious how the (er, "alleged") русский meddling in the US election is playing there, but that's for a different time and place.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: well, it's kinda obvious. In `3.*(a).+(2)` all method arguments are parenthesized and methods are called "left to right", as always (for example, `project.user.name`). in `3.*a.+2`, the expressions are parsed/folded "inside-out" (as in `puts rand 10`), so it is `3.*(a.+(2))` and you get corresponding result. Operator precedence does not apply here because these are unambiguous method calls.

Comment: re-reading what I posted, I must be not explaining this clearly, but it's the best I can do at the moment :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I assume you were just tired, but `(3.).is_a?(Integer)` doesn't work because `3.` is not a valid float. `3.*(a)` on the other hand is just `3 * a`, but written as a method call (the `*` method called on the object `3` with an argument of `a`). As for the precedence, that was already well explained by Sergio.

Comment: Sergio and @Michael, oh my!

Comment: Thanks, it actually isn't above my level (I'm lacking Ruby academia, but real world coding I'm more than familiar with). I just hadn't run into this (mainly because like you mentioned, you wouldn't see it likely in a real world app like I work in. But wanted to reinforce my knowledge) and was wondering the right direction. Thank you for providing it for me! And the details.